# Creating a Set from a Vector with custom sort

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a set from given Vector, which takes a custom sort to store the elements. One way, i tried doing was Create a set with customSortFnc `set<string> my_set(my_comp)` and loop through the vector and add each one to set. Instead of this, is there a short hand (which removes writing the for loop to iterate vector) to do the same?

For Example:
If my `Vector<string>` is `vector<string> words = {"a","b","ba","bca","bda","bdca"};`
The set should have unique values stored in order sorted by length, where the longest string comes first.

Expected Set output => `{"bdca", "bda", "bca", "ba", "b", "a"}`

Also, how to do this when trying to convert `vector<CustomClass>` to `set<CustomClass>` using custom sort function.

Answer (score 2):

With a constructor that takes a range of iterators. Something like:

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct my_sorter {
  bool operator()(const std::string &a, const std::string &b) const noexcept {
    if (a.length() == b.length()) {
      return a > b;
    } else {
      return a.length() > b.length();
    }      
  }
};

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> words = {"a","b","ba","bca","bda","bdca"};
  std::set<std::string, my_sorter> wordset(words.begin(), words.end());

  for (const auto &s : wordset) {
    std::cout << s << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If you add, say, `"bd"` to the list of strings, that will result in a wrong order from what OP wants.

Comment: Oh, good catch, I was primarily looking at the result rather than the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, like this

```
set<string> my_set(words.begin(), words.end(), my_comp);
```

Most STL collections have a constructor which takes a pair of iterators. So it's very easy to populate one collection from the elements of another collection.

Exactly the same code will work when you have a custom class (assuming my_comp works for the custom class).

Comment: I guess you need to specify the second template parameter for `set` or omit the first one for CTAD.

Comment: @Evg, yes perhaps you need something like `set<string, bool (*)(string, string)>` but the OP omitted the template parameter in their code so I was unsure what to do.

Comment: Something like `set<string, decltype(my_comp)>` should work.